# Подскажите, как из значений словаря, сделать другой словарь Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь из 2 ключей и значений:

```
dict1 = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1}
```

Мне нужно сделать новый словарь, где A - ключ, а 1 - его значение:

```
dict2 = {'A': 1}
```

Я пробовал через `for`, но у меня получалось выводить только значения и все.

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: ну так попробуй в своем цикле for не выводить значения, а присваивать их.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно что-то в этом роде?

```
dict1 = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1}
dict2 = {dict1['symbol']: dict1['value']}
```

Тогда не понимаю зачем вам цикл...

Comment: Да, именно это мне и надо было, но я уже сам сделал. Но все равно спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, вдруг кому пригодится
`pip install more-itertools`

```py
from more_itertools import chunked
d = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1}

vd = dict(chunked(d.values(), 2))
```

---

```
{'A': 1}
```

**только в том случае, если вы уверены в том, что словарь в переменной `d` содержит четное количество элементов.*
Или можно не мудрить с библиотекой, и написать подобную функцию самому

```py
def chunked(it: Sized, part_size: int):        
    for n in range(0, part_size, len(it)):
        yield it[n: n + part_size]
```

**В этом случае `d.values()` нужно привести к списку*

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что показал [@Namerek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397399/namerek), но без сторонних модулей, в лоб:

```
dict1 = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1}
a=list(dict1.values())
a=[(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
dict_2=dict(a)
print(dict_2)
```

Вывод:

```
{'A': 1}
```

Работает со всеми словарями, в которых содержится *чётное* число элементов. Доказательство:

```
dict1 = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1, 'foo':'bar', 'x':10}
```

Вывод:

```
{'A': 1, 'bar': 10}
```

---

Для тех, кто любит однострочники:)

```
dict1 = {'symbol': 'A', 'value': 1}
print(dict([(list(dict1.values())[i],list(dict1.values())[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(list(dict1.values())),2)]))
```